# how to add text to html control removing span class

Tags: c#, html

I have button in my user control like

```
<button class="show-form-button" runat="server" ID="btnShow">Please submit<span class="icon-down"></span></button>
```

In my code behind I am setting text of button but it is somehow removing span class when page is rendered

```
btnShow.InnerText = "Submitted";
```

How do I retain span class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Innertext` will replace the entire contents of the tag with the supplied text. To retain the icon, replace the inner HTML with `"Submitted<span class='icon-down'></span>"`